# pvcreate disk filtered while filter is set and no mpath

Tags: lvm, ovirt

I have been fighting with an issue on CentOS 7.6.1801 on a HP over HW RAID. I searched a lot and tried many options about I still can't fix this.  May be I overlook something. I hope someone can spot it.

`# pvcreate  /dev/sdb 
  Device /dev/sdb excluded by a filter.`

`# lsblk /dev/sdb
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb    8:16   0  6.6T  0 disk`

`/etc/lvm/lvm.conf  :
filter = ["a|^/dev/sda2$|", "r|.*|"]
global_filter = ["a|/dev/sdb |"]`

==========

(parted) print
Model: HPE LOGICAL VOLUME (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 7201GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags

(parted)

==============

`# pvcreate  /dev/sdb  -vv
(removed lines with sda)

```
  Setting devices/global_filter to global_filter = [ "a|/dev/sdb |" ]
  devices/cache not found in config: defaulting to /etc/lvm/cache/.cache
  metadata/record_lvs_history not found in config: defaulting to 0
  File-based locking selected.
  metadata/pvmetadataignore not found in config: defaulting to 0
  metadata/pvmetadatasize not found in config: defaulting to 255
  metadata/pvmetadatacopies not found in config: defaulting to 1
  report/output_format not found in config: defaulting to basic
  log/report_command_log not found in config: defaulting to 0
  Locking /run/lock/lvm/P_orphans WB
  devices/cache not found in config: defaulting to /etc/lvm/cache/.cache
```

Device /dev/sdb excluded by a filter.
      Unlocking /run/lock/lvm/P_orphans`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overlooked some whitespace.

```
global_filter = ["a|/dev/sdb |"]
```

Did you miss the space after `sdb`? That should not be there. If you are trying to match `/dev/sdb`, then this will fail to match because of the space.